# how can i get another form input verified in play?

Tags: forms, scala, input, playframework-2.0

This is my code based on the examples:

```
val signupForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "firstname" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastname"  -> nonEmptyText,
      "email"     -> nonEmptyText,
      "password1" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password2" -> nonEmptyText,
      "phone"     -> optional(text)
    )   verifying ("That email address already exists please contact an administrator.", result => result match {
      case (firstname, lastname, email, password1, password2, phone) => !User.checkexists(email).isDefined 
    })
    )
```

but there is no example showing how i might add another check in there - say comparing the password1 & password2... or a third check...

where can i add another 'verifying ' bit?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val signupForm = Form(
  tuple(
    ...
  ) verifying (...)
  verifying (...)
  verifying (...)
)
```

In your case:

```
val signupForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "firstname" -> nonEmptyText,
    "lastname"  -> nonEmptyText,
    "email"     -> nonEmptyText,
    "password1" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password2" -> nonEmptyText,
    "phone"     -> optional(text)
  )   verifying ("That email address already exists please contact an administrator.", result => result match {
    case (firstname, lastname, email, password1, password2, phone) => !User.checkexists(email).isDefined 
  })
  verifying (...)
)
```